# Could anyone help me decipher this?

Tags: перевод

[image]

Could anyone help me "decipher" this word below the arrow? I'm guessing its Priroda ("Nature"). But would be great if someone else could have a look at it for me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This word is "Лирика".
And the first line is `из цикла "Лирика"`.

Comment: Thank you, that corroborates with surrounding evidence! (This handwriting is from 1921)